# Is there a Community Moderator Election for 2013?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election

During the latter part of the previous we had community moderator elections for [Android.SE]. We are now almost done with the year 2013 and there is no news or announcement such event? Are we not going to have one this year? And why so if we are not?

Comment: I'm not interested in being a candidate whatsoever. But still I'd like to know what's going on.

Comment: I haven't heard anything about one. The moderator workload seems to be covered, so no new mods are needed. (The existing mods have life terms, unless they step down or begin doing a poor job.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderator elections are [held when new moderators are needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166054/when-are-moderator-elections). Matthew already stated that we are covered, so I don't expect an election this year.